# Exchange 2013 Urls and settings

Tags: exchange

Having a bit of a problem with my  greenfield installation of Exchange Server 2013.
Environment: Windows Server 2012, 4 Exchange Servers (collocated CAS/MBX roles), Outlook 2010.

HLB is arriving next week, until then I have configured DNS RR for both autodiscover.company.com and mail.company.com.

If starting outlook on a domain joined pc, autodiscover and outlook anywhere is working perfect.
If starting outlook on a non-domain joined pc and enter my email address it does an autodiscover lookup using A record (autodiscover.company.com) and it resolves the guid. but I cannot logon to the server. If I do it manually I cannt enter the proxyname (mail.company.com) I have to enter a exchangeservernamefqdn, then it works.

- Certificate: 3rd party wildcard, stampled on IIS services on all servers. OWA/ECP works perfect.
- Outlook Provider: EXPR mail.company.com msstd:*.company.com
- Outlook Anywhere (RPC vDir): InternalUrl/ExternalUrl: mail.company.com (External=Negotiate, Internal = NTLM)
- Exchange WebServices (EWS vDir): InternalUrl/ExternalUrl: https://mail.company.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx, InternalNLBBypassUrl: https://srvfqdn.company.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx (tried $null and mail.company.com as well)
- ClientAccessServer/AutodisocverServiceInternalUri: https://mail.company.com/Autodiscover/Autodiscover.xml

1) So domainjoined pc works perfekt, but not non-domain joined (never gets pass the basic screen).

2) Test-OutlookWebServices = Autodiscover: Outlook Provider failure (if using -debug I cannot see any errors).

3) How come if using netstat on a client computer I can see the connection towards the server hosting the active mailboxdatabase. Should'nt I see the proxy (mail.company.com?)

4) Shall InternalNLBBypassUrl be serverfqdn, proxy fqdn or $null?
When first installed it was empty, but after a reset of ews vdir it got the serverfqdn field configured!

Comment: Does anybody know if InternalNLBBypass URL already be used in Exchange 2013? (EWS proxying for example).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an answer as to what's wrong, but you might try using the Microsoft Remote Connectivity Analyzer: https://www.testexchangeconnectivity.com/

I found it very helpful when I was debugging autodiscover failures with 2010.

Comment: Hi scott, we have not yet deployed UAG for external access and the new feature that we can download and run on a local computer is telling us that everything is OK.

Answer (score 1):

I have had such problem two times... In my case the problem was in authentication type which was configured by default as **Negotiate** for external clients, so I've changed it to **Basic** and the problem has gone.

**For Exchange 2010:**

```
Get-OutlookAnywhere | Set-OutlookAnywhere -ClientAuthenticationMethod "Basic"
```

**For Exchange 2013:**

```
Get-OutlookAnywhere | Set-OutlookAnywhere -ExternalClientAuthenticationMethod "Basic"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is mail.company.com your Client Access Server for each of the Mailbox Servers?

If you run:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase |ft name, rpcclientaccessserver
```

You'll get a list of the Client Access Servers for each Mailbox Database.

It's common to point all the client access to a single namespace and load balance on it.
This command will set all the Mailbox servers to use CAS.company.com as the client access server:

```
Get-MailboxDatabase | Set-MailboxDatabase -RpcClientAccessServer "CAS.company.com"
```

Comment: Hi Azraellin, that RpcClientAccessServer attribut has been depricated and belongs to the CASArray funkction within Exchange 2010. In Exchange Server 2013 it is still there but the attribute cannot be changed.